# Collection-like interface inheriting from Collection

Tags: java, collections, interface

I have a collection-like interface that contains most methods of the `Collection` interface, but there is a problem related to the `add` and `contains` method that am am concerned about to simply inherit from `Collection`.

The elements of type `T` in the `Collection` implement a `copy` method and a setter that is sometimes required in the following manner:

- Alter the element before inserting it via the provided setter
- Create a copy of the element, alter one or both elements via the provided setter and only then insert them

One could visualize this by thinking of a collection that takes string arguments, but if a particular string `foo` is added, a truncated version `fo` or, `fo` plus another string `bar` is added.

```
// Examples of the add() method internals
collection.add("foo"); // internally add("fo");
collection.add("foo"); // internally add("fo"); add("bar");
```

The problem is, that sometimes more than one element is inserted, which itself is fine with the method contract from `add`, but altering the element before insertion is somewhat dirty. If the `copy` method is used and the element is inserted, it would not `contain` the original element anymore.

Question: Would it be correct to extend `Collection` non the less or is redefining most the collection methods a better option here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your interface should not extend `Collection` if it behaves as you describe, since it does violate the contract of `Collection`'s `add`, which says:

> Ensures that this collection contains the specified element

and

> If a collection refuses to add a particular element for any reason other than that it already contains the element, it must throw an exception (rather than returning false). This preserves the invariant that a collection always contains the specified element after this call returns.

If `collection.add("foo");` actually adds "fo", then the contract is broken.

If your interface extends `Collection`, a user of your interface can assign an instance of your interface to a `Collection` variable, and expect it to behave as described in the `Collection` interface.

Comment: Adding on from the Doc, just to make it clearer -
    If a collection refuses to add a particular element for any reason
     * other than that it already contains the element, it <i>must</i> throw
     * an exception (rather than returning <tt>false</tt>)

Answer (score 1):

Adding on to @Eran's answer.

From the Docs

```
If a collection refuses to add a particular element for any reason
other than that it already contains the element, it must throw
an exception (rather than returning false)
```

Don't use the add method. You can instead extend the Collection and add a new method which follows your contract. Something on the lines of

```
boolean addOrSplit(E e) {
    if(contains(e)) {
         //split e
         //addOrSplit(e - Part1);
         //addOrSplit(e - Part2);
    } else {
         add(e);
    }
}
```

Make sure you handle the recursion end condition and avoid infinite loops in this implementation.